# Looping through variables to find the content (a number) which occures the most

Tags: php

I have a number of returned values from a query, example 3,1,1,4,2
In my example 1 occurs more times than any other number.

The actual variables returned are:

```
$row_Feedback ['a']; // 3
$row_Feedback ['b']; // 1
$row_Feedback ['c']; // 1
$row_Feedback ['d']; // 4
$row_Feedback ['e']; // 2
```

How can I loop through each of the numbers to find which number occures the most.

I have reseached this for hours, trying different approaches use array_count but I am totally stuck.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: `In my example 3 occures more times than any other number.`->No it's 1

Comment: Take a look at PHP's [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function

Comment: Updated my post to more reflect  In my example 3 occures more times than any other number to  In my example 1 occures more times than any other number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_count_values()` like below:-

```
<?php
 $array = array('a'=>3,'b'=>1,'c'=>1,'d'=>4,'e'=>2);
 print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Output:-https://eval.in/817184

And if you want that number then:-

```
<?php
$array = array('a'=>3,'b'=>1,'c'=>1,'d'=>4,'e'=>2);
$count=array_count_values($array);
arsort($count);
$keys=array_keys($count);
echo "The most occuring value is ".$keys[0]." with ".$count[$keys[0]]." occurences";
```

Output:- https://eval.in/817196   Or https://eval.in/817197